# MVC Bundling & Minification with less isn't working with import

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, less, bundling-and-minification

I'm trying to use Metro-bootstrap (http://talkslab.github.com/metro-bootstrap/) in VS 2012 with an MVC 4 project.  I followed the steps in this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593254/mvc4-less-bundle-import-directory) but I'm still getting an error about a file with a .less extension not being found when trying to parse metro-bootstrap.less.  The error is happening when calling @import.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach: http://blog.cdeutsch.com/2012/08/using-less-and-twitter-bootstrap-in.html
If the problem continues after this, could you post your bundles and the details of the error?