# Bundler & Minifier, CSS Minification Errors on @imports and @keyframes

Tags: css, visual-studio, bundler, minify

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I just installed Bundler & Minifier extension to minimize HTML, JS and CSS code.

When I ran my project I get a lot of errors.. here I'm showing some of them.

This is en example of my code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300');
@charset "UTF-8";
```

This are the errors:

@import not allowed here.

@charset not allowed here.

(Bundler & Minifier) Expected expression, found '}'

Do you have any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: It's reported here on the Bundler & Minifier 
github https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/191 ?

Comment: Yes, but there is not a solution

Comment: I found the solution...See below...thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer helped me a lot.

[Minification failed. Returning unminified contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395412/minification-failed-returning-unminified-contents)

@Import must always be first in the CSS document. When you bundle multipule CSS files together, it chains them into a single bundled css file. Since the second css file added to my bundle, in bundle config, contained an @Import at the start, as the files were chained together the @import appeared towards the middle of the newly merged document. Once I changed the bundle order the issue was resolve.