# BundleTransformer: CSS not bundled through @import directive

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, less, bundle

We are using the `BundleTransformer` in our ASP.NET MVC project to bundle our style files.

This works great, but we noticed that some CSS files are not bundled with our LESS files when we important them in LESS with the `@import` CSS at-rule.

Sample in our root LESS file:

```
/* Import core LESS files */
@import "../core.less";

/* Import jQuery UI stuff*/
@import "../themes/base/core.css";
@import "../themes/base/resizable.css";
@import "../themes/base/accordion.css";
@import "../themes/base/tabs.css";

/* Import more LESS files */
@import "../morestyles.less";
```

If we look at the files that are downloaded from Chrome, it is clear that the CSS files are not bundled with the root LESS files.

[image: Chrome Network Screen Capture]

Naturally, we could simply include these CSS files in the BundleConfig and remove the `@import` calls, but I was just curious to see if there is a way to have them bundled together.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9593254/mvc4-less-bundle-import-directory .. might help. http://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Less

Comment: @gerdi: Thanks, but we are already using the BundleTransformer.Less package. Bundling would not have worked at all if we didn't.

Comment: Ah right, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read http://lesscss.org/features/#import-options.

In your code `@import "../themes/base/tabs.css";` compiles into `@import "../themes/base/tabs.css";` (due to the `.css` extension). Which is a "normal" CSS import, CSS imports require an additional HTTP request to load.

You can use the `inline` option:

```
@import (inline) "../themes/base/tabs.css";
```

The above inlines the code from tabs.css into your project file without processing it.

Comment: Legend! All the Bass now belongs to you. Thanks!